# SELinux sandboxed firefox has no audio

Tags: fedora, selinux, sandbox, xephyr

Running firefox in a SELinux sandbox using this script:

```
Random variables for directories, Allowing multiple instances
SEhome=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
SEtemp=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
mkdir /tmp/sehome.$SEhome
mkdir /tmp/setemp.$SEtemp

# run sandbox instance
sandbox -X -H /tmp/sehome.$SEhome -T /tmp/setemp.$SEtemp -t sandbox_web_t -t sandbox_net_t -w 3440x1440 firefox  --no-remote

# destroy temporary directories
rm -rf /tmp/sehome.$SEhome
rm -rf /tmp/setemp.$SEtemp
```

As of Fedora 38, audio no longer works.

audit2allow -s is quiet and
I cant really find much in the logs: 
/var/log/messages

```
May 25 18:31:14 localhost dbus-broker[1899]: A security policy denied :1.1206 to send method call /org/freedesktop/RealtimeKit1:org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get to org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.
May 25 18:31:14 localhost rsyslogd[1821]: imjournal: 27485 messages lost due to rate-limiting (20000 allowed within 600 seconds)
```

/var/log/audit/audit.log

```
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1685032214.075:23247): pid=25443 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'UID="delta" AUID="delta"
type=USER_START msg=audit(1685032214.107:23248): pid=25443 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix,pam_umask,pam_xauth acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'UID="delta" AUID="delta"
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1685032231.705:23249): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=pcscd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1685032239.160:23250): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=fprintd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=BPF msg=audit(1685032239.168:23251): prog-id=7441 op=UNLOAD
```

Any ideas on where to start? i consider myself semi-skilled at linux, but i am not a SElinux buff.

Comment: Happening in FC37 too. Was working fine in FC36.

Comment: You can start a pulseaudio instance in the sandbox to get it working, its buggy and no where near perfect, but you'll get sound through..

Comment: How? I haven't found how to run other processes inside the sandbox running Firefox. Also, do you mean `pipewire-pulse`? It appears that stock pulseaudio is obsolete.

Comment: Force install the pulseaudio.rpm from fedora and then simpy run pulseaudio & in your sandbox before launching firefox.

It allows for an audio connection, buts its not great.